# Scrolling listbox to the end using selectedItem

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Here is my code:

```
        lbLog.Items.Add("Something");
        lbLog.SelectedIndex = (lbLog.Items.Count - 1);
```

This works in scrolling the listBox to the last entry, but I don't want the last entry to have that "blue" selected color on it. Is it possible to do this but not have the last item appear selected to the user?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lbLog.SelectedIndex= -1;
```

Makes your current selection get focused with that blue color.
Add this code after you made your selection.

Answer (score 1):

add `.SelectedIndex = -1;` to the last code

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it myself, simply add:

```
lbLog.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

At the bottom, with the final code looking like:

```
    lbLog.Items.Add("Something");
    lbLog.SelectedIndex = (lbLog.Items.Count - 1);
    lbLog.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it will scroll to the last item but will not select it.

```
lbLog.TopIndex = lbLog.Items.Count - 1;
```